# Set table equal to CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table A, that I regularly want to update from another table B.
I can create a CTE from B that looks exactly like I want table A to look like, but I can't find the syntax for setting A equal to CTE. What I want is something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ARRAY_AGG(column_name),
        ...
    FROM B
)
UPDATE A
SET 
    A = cte
FROM cte
```

Comment: Relational SQL does not work this way, namely entire tables can't be updated to other tables.  Instead, updates in SQL operate on individual _records_.  Please add some sample data to your question for best results.

Comment: Truncate or delete and the insert, or try using merge (though that has some complications if you want to get rid of old records not in B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should provide some condition and columns names:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ARRAY_AGG(column_name),
        ...
    FROM B
)
UPDATE A
SET 
  --You need to name the columns
    A.column1 = cte.column1,
    A.column2 = cte.column2
FROM cte
  --You need to provide some condition
where A.id=cte.ID
```

Or do you want to replace table A completely?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ARRAY_AGG(column_name),
        ...
    FROM B
)

delete from A
where 1=1

insert into A(column1,column2)
select column1,column2 from cte
```